# How do I show a graph in responsive way that works in desktop and mobile portrait and landscape?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I want to show a graph within a div.

Aspect ratio is height 50 % of width.

The graph in question looks like this:

http://simkimsia.github.io/500-charts/dygraphs/range-selector/

[image]

How do I make this div work in a responsive way in desktop and mobile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming this div is responsible for the graph

```
  <p>No roll period.</p>
  <div id="noroll"></div>
```

First set the position of the div

```
    <style type="text/css">
      #noroll {
        position: absolute;
        left: 10px;
        right: 10px;
        top: 40px;
        bottom: 10px;
      }
    </style>
```

Then do not add any height or width styles to the div.

The dygraphs js will auto resize.

Reference: code https://github.com/danvk/dygraphs/blob/master/tests/resize.html
Reference: example http://dygraphs.com/tests/resize.html

Answer (score 2):

I am astonished to find that the danvk example works the way that Kim Stacks says: if you delete the position:absolute and put in any width setting then there is no resizing (I forgot exactly what happens but it is not pleasant).

My other reason for astonishment is that I've been using Dygraphs for years and mine resize and I didn't do any of that position:absolute jazz. I instead put the graph inside a table:

```
<table style="margin:auto;width:90%;text-align:center;"><tr><td>
    <div id="div_g"></div>
</td></tr></table>
```

And for the div I have the following:

```
<style type="text/css">
    #div_g {height:320px;margin-top:50px;width=100%;}
</style>
```

That is, I downloaded danvk's example, NoisyData function and all, and ran it as above. It works. I get resizing. Chrome and Firefox both pass it on the narrowest screen.

If this isn't perfectly clear, setting "top:40px" and "position:absolute" is not going to fly as an acceptable HTML page layout discipline (here the 40px are to avoid drawing the graph on top of "Resize the window. The dygraph will resize with it."

Note especially that I found it *necessary* to set a height with this setup.

Now I will admit that, for reasons that I can't figure out, one of two pages that I have Dygraphs on that are setup this way just recently gave me a Google fail on mobile readiness. I fixed it in a painful manner by specifying the Dygraph div container widths as follows:

```
function adjustStyle(width) {
  var width = parseInt(width);
  if (width < 480) {
    $(".dygraphplot").attr("style", "height:290px;max-width:290px;margin-bottom:10px;");
  } else if (width < 540) {
    $(".dygraphplot").attr("style", "height:320px;max-width:480px;margin-bottom:10px;");
  } else if (width < 600) {
    $(".dygraphplot").attr("style", "height:320px;max-width:540px;margin-bottom:10px;");
  } else if (width < 640) {
    $(".dygraphplot").attr("style", "height:320px;max-width:600px;margin-bottom:10px;");
  } else if (width < 720) {
    $(".dygraphplot").attr("style", "height:320px;max-width:640px;margin-bottom:10px;");
  } else if (width < 750) {
    $(".dygraphplot").attr("style", "height:320px;max-width:720px;margin-bottom:10px;");
  } else if (width < 768) {
    $(".dygraphplot").attr("style", "height:320px;max-width:750px;margin-bottom:10px;");
  } else if (width < 800) {
    $(".dygraphplot").attr("style", "height:320px;max-width:768px;margin-bottom:10px;");
  } else if (width < 1080) {
    $(".dygraphplot").attr("style", "height:320px;max-width:800px;margin-bottom:10px;");
  } else if (width < 1200) {
    $(".dygraphplot").attr("style", "height:320px;max-width:1080px;margin-bottom:10px;");
  } else if (width < 1440) {
    $(".dygraphplot").attr("style", "height:320px;max-width:1200px;margin-bottom:10px;");
  } else if (width < 1536) {
    $(".dygraphplot").attr("style", "height:320px;max-width:1440px;margin-bottom:10px;");
  } else if (width < 1538) {
    $(".dygraphplot").attr("style", "height:320px;max-width:1536px;margin-bottom:10px;");
  } else if (width < 1600) {
    $(".dygraphplot").attr("style", "height:320px;max-width:1538px;margin-bottom:10px;");
  } else {
     $(".dygraphplot").attr("style", "height:320px;max-width:1538px;margin-bottom:10px;"); 
  }
```

}

See the JQuery panel on [this page](https://css-tricks.com/resolution-specific-stylesheets/) for the document-ready invocation of this function. Of course "dygraphplot" is the name of a class that I gave to the Dygraph div.

If I can find out why my other page still works without all of this I'll go back to that scheme.

Answer (score -1):

You can either try using that image with a framework that handles image responsiveness, such as [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#images)

> Images in Bootstrap 3 can be made responsive-friendly via the addition of the .img-responsive class. This applies max-width: 100%; and height: auto; to the image so that it scales nicely to the parent element.

Or by far a much better approach, using a chart framework such as (but not limited to) http://www.chartjs.org/

Comment: I am using dygraphs already. Dygraphs rely on the size of the div. Hence my question is still valid. However, I will try your max-width:100% and height: auto;

Comment: @KimStacks or use Bootstrap and enclose the Dygraphs image into a column that will resize itself on viewport size.